# Does anyone know how to get multi-bay USB HDD docking station to recognize more than the HDD1?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, docking

I have a Vantec Dual Bay SATA HDD docking station and a Hornettek quad bay SATA HDD docking station.  Ubuntu 18.04 will recognize ONLY HDD1 on these devices.  Anyone have a solution?  Seems like a waste of money to have bought them and they don't work.

Comment: did you do a `modprobe ahci`? Both seem to be supported by linux (smartmontools lists the vantec as supported. maybe install that too?)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, there are some information about it. This one is legit. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/how-to-mount-a-hard-drive-dock-4175504607/

Comment: When I switch the drives (on the Hornettek) they are both recognized.  I'll keep them where they are!